# How do I get the Client Hostname and/or client IP address from within a Spring Boot application in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

For one of my APIs, I am need to check the client hostname address.

I am using

```
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
String hostname = request.getRemoteHost();
```

(where `request` is a `HttpServletRequest`).

I know that the HTTP spec and the Java servlet spec both say that both of these values may be absent. However, I am seeing that each time the value for *both* is "127.0.0.1".

I assume that the way Elastic Beanstalk is set up, all requests to the VM come from within.
Is there a way to retrieve the client address header from within?

If I use CloudFront for HTTPS termination, is there a way to have it pass the client address through?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cope with x-forwarded-headers in Spring Boot 2.2.0? (Spring Web MVC behind reverse proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126518/how-to-cope-with-x-forwarded-headers-in-spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-web-mvc-behin)

Comment: Or this one? [Elastic Load Balancer not passing X-Forwarded-For in Beanstalk app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21433472/476716)

Comment: Or this one? [Retrieving CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25823151/476716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to the question is that AWS Elastic Beanstalk gets requests via a local proxy. CloudFront also acts as a reverse proxy.

The solution is to use the `X-Forwarded-For` header on the request.

This is a de-facto standard header used by HTTP proxy servers.

This is a multi-value header - populated by each proxy along the way. The first entry is the actual remote client address. Subsequent values are for proxy hosts.

`request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")` will give you the raw value.

`request.getHeaders("X-Forwarded-For")` will give you an `Enumeration<String>`[1], which you can iterate through to get individual values.

[1] `Enumeration` is an interface - the most common implementation of which is a `Vector`. Iterate as follows

```
Enumeration<String> headers = ...;

while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
  String header =  headers.nextElement();
  // TODO: process header ...
}
```